# Simple Class A Output Power Stage of Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, distortion, class-a

I made this circuit and the output signal wasn't really what I was expecting to be.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTz38Am.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is class A amplifier (both Q1 and Q2 conducting both negative and positive half cycles). I was only curious how the signal from V1 is buffered to the output and I am already (at this point) insecure about its operation.

Here is the measurement of a signal I scoped:

[image]

As can be seen, there is a "double-amplitude" signal at the point where I probed the circuit.

- Is this the consequence of Q1 and Q2 constantly conducting the signal?

Comment: You should consider replacing R1 and R2 with diodes, also the 47k ohm resistors seem to be quite on the high side, you dont mention what your load will be, if you are planning on using low ohm loads, then I would definitely use smaller resistors for R3 and R4. Also, you are not using any feedback, so distortion of the output waveform is expected.

Comment: I expect that only one transistor is conducting at any time, as you have shorted their bases together.

Comment: The circuit is incorrect, you have Q1 and Q2 bases shorted. @PeterBennett Adding diodes won't help as this makes it a Class AB amplifier

Comment: @JackCreasey Ah thank you for spoting that mistake.

Comment: Looks like 60Hz mains hum. Increase the scope timebase until the 'double amplitude' signal becomes a single waveform. Do you see the signal waving up and down at a lower frequency?

Comment: This is class B, not AB.

Comment: @mkeith Define the difference between class AB and B since you are so sure about it.

Comment: Lots of resources online. The basic idea is that if the output devices are both off when the output signal crosses through zero volts, then it is a class B amplifier. I think you intended to make a class AB, but accidentally made a class B because the bases of the output devices are tied together.

Comment: @mkeith No no, I was trying to get as close as possible to class B amplifier but I see now that pure class B amplifier is practically impossible unless both transistors are biased in such way that one conducts only positive polarity signals and the other one conducts only negative polarity signals - as the npn side would conduct output signal exactly positive side of signal and then turn of while at the same time pnp side of transistors would turn on and conduct... , which seems to me practically impossible to make such biasing conditions. What do you think?

Comment: @mkeith Yes I will correct that with the bases.

Comment: I don't know that much about audio amplifiers, but I read one of Doug Self's books on the topic. I think the simplest thing is to use a Vbe multiplier with a trim pot between the two bases. Then fine tune the bias current. The bias current will change as the output transistors heat up. So that is another thing to watch out for.